# biblatex: If comma-separated organizational unit names as publisher are braced individually, most disappear — why?

Tags: biblatex

Suppose I, using `biblatex`, want to cite a publication of a government office and include the names of its parent agencies as the publisher, as in, *e.g.*, [APA style](https://apastyle.apa.org/style-grammar-guidelines/references/elements-list-entry#groupname). Suppose these agency names include the word "and". Per the `biblatex` manual, §2.3.4, if a publisher's name contains the word "and", either the "and" or the whole name must be braced to escape the "and" from being interpreted as a list separator. Either bracing the "and"s or (double-)bracing the whole `publisher` values does work. However, if I brace the names of the individual organizational units within the `publisher` field, the output seems strange — the first organizational unit is shown as the publisher, but the succeeding ones are omitted.

The following example document demonstrates by creating a reference list in which a publisher field is given with bracing of the "and"s, with bracing of the whole value, and with bracing of the names of the individual organizational units. This is demonstrated with both the `book` and the `misc` entry types (the latter using `organization` rather than `publisher`).

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{\jobname.bib}
@book{book1,
    title={Book 1},
    author={A.},
    date={2013},
    publisher={Republic of Foo {and} Bar, Ministry of Education {and} Science, Office for Food {and} Agriculture},
}
@book{book2,
    title={Book 2},
    author={A.},
    date={2013},
    publisher={{Republic of Foo and Bar, Ministry of Education and Science, Office for Food and Agriculture}},
}
@book{book3,
    title={Book 3},
    author={A.},
    date={2013},
    publisher={{Republic of Foo and Bar}, {Ministry of Education and Science}, {Office for Food and Agriculture}},
}
@misc{misc1,
    title={Misc 1},
    author={A.},
    date={2013},
    organization={Republic of Foo {and} Bar, Ministry of Education {and} Science, Office for Food {and} Agriculture},
}
@misc{misc2,
    title={Misc 2},
    author={A.},
    date={2013},
    organization={{Republic of Foo and Bar, Ministry of Education and Science, Office for Food and Agriculture}},
}
@misc{misc3,
    title={Misc 3},
    author={A.},
    date={2013},
    organization={{Republic of Foo and Bar}, {Ministry of Education and Science}, {Office for Food and Agriculture}},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

\nocite{*}
\printbibliography[]

\end{document}
```

Note that the `publisher` (and `organization`) fields are given in the following forms:

1. `publisher={A {and} B, C {and} D, E {and} F}`,
2. `publisher={{A and B, C and D, E and F}}`, and
3. `publisher={{A and B}, {C and D}, {E and F}}`.

This is the result (formatted as well as a code block allows):

```
References

[1] A. Book 1. Republic of Foo and Bar, Ministry of Education and Science,
    Office for Food and Agriculture, 2013.
[2] A. Book 2. Republic of Foo and Bar, Ministry of Education and Science,
    Office for Food and Agriculture, 2013.
[3] A. Book 3. Republic of Foo and Bar, 2013.
[4] A. Misc 1. Republic of Foo and Bar, Ministry of Education and Science,
    Office for Food and Agriculture, 2013.
[5] A. Misc 2. Republic of Foo and Bar, Ministry of Education and Science,
    Office for Food and Agriculture, 2013.
[6] A. Misc 3. Republic of Foo and Bar, 2013
```

Note that, where the form `publisher={{A and B}, {C and D}, {E and F}}` was used, everything after and including the first comma disappeared. **My questions are:**

1. **Why? What does `publisher={{A}, {B}, {C}}` mean to `biblatex` that I'm not realizing?**
2. **Where should I have found that in the `biblatex` manual?**

Comment: I believe you're misunderstanding the difference between author and publisher.

Comment: As my hyperlink shows, at least one significant US citation style [says](https://apastyle.apa.org/style-grammar-guidelines/references/elements-list-entry#groupname) to put "[t]he names of parent agencies not present in the group author name [...] as the publisher". Even regardless of what I'm putting in the publisher field, it seems strange for the `, {B}, {C}` to disappear from `publisher={{A}, {B}, {C}}`.

Comment: I’m not sure what the question is. The braces in the `publisher` field are irrelevant, as far as I can see.

Comment: @egreg not really, if you don't put braces then the publisher is listed as _Republic of Foo et al._ so biblatex by default treats the publisher field the same as an author field. It may be useful in some cases to allow processing on the publisher field, however I was surprised to see that this is the default behavior, I would suspect that in most cases the publisher name should just be included as-is.

Comment: @Marijn That’s indeed surprising

Comment: I edited my post to try to make more clear what I find unexpected (that "everything after and including the first comma disappeared" in some cases).

Comment: @Marijn The behaviour that publisher names (lists) are treated as author names is deliberate in BibLaTeX. However, as with author names (`maxbibnames`) you can set the maximal number of list elements printed before "et al." - using `maxitems` if I remember correctly. As with the `namedelim`, you can also change the delimiter between list elements, using `listdelim`/`finallistdelim`. But I also do not understand, why the bracing does not work as one would assume.

Comment: @Marijn Wait, I just saw you used `publisher={{Republic of Foo and Bar}, {Ministry of Education and Science}, {Office for Food and Agriculture}}`. That means, you use commas to separate elements. I would assume `publisher={{Republic of Foo and Bar} and {Ministry of Education and Science} and {Office for Food and Agriculture}}` should give you the correct output.

Comment: @ManuelWeinkauf: Did you mean me? The (fictitious) Office is a subunit of the Ministry, which is a subunit of the Republic; they're not three separate organizations. "Republic of Foo and Bar, Ministry of Education and Science, Office for Food and Agriculture" is an *absolute path*, with the comma as the path element separator, as seen, e.g., [here](https://apastyle.apa.org/style-grammar-guidelines/references/elements-list-entry#groupname).

Comment: @user570286 The correct input seems to be the one for “Book 2”, with additional braces around the whole entry.

Comment: @user570286 Yes sorry. I posted a solution which I think does what you want. You must use the `and` separator to separate elements in lists, in generic lists as with names.

Comment: It's not meant to mean a list of three separate organizations; it's the Republic of Foo and Bar's Ministry of Education and Science's Office for Food and Agriculture: a single organization.

Comment: OK, but in that case I agree with egreg. Your entry for book2 is actually the correct way how you should write it to keep together everything that belongs to one entity. Is there any reason why that cannot be done.

Comment: @ManuelWeinkauf: Indeed, there is no reason that cannot be done, but "how to get the output I want" isn't one of my questions here. I've bolded my questions to try to make this clearer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the moment this looks like a Biber bug to me, so I reported the issue at https://github.com/plk/biber/issues/370.

In the following example

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{book1,
  title     = {Book 1},
  author    = {A.},
  date      = {2011},
  publisher = {A {and} B, C {and} D, E {and} F},
}
@book{book2,
  title     = {Book 2},
  author    = {A.},
  date      = {2012},
  publisher = {{A and B, C and D, E and F}},
}
@book{book3,
  title     = {Book 3},
  author    = {A.},
  date      = {2013},
  publisher = {{A and B}, {C and D}, {E and F}},
}
@book{compare,
  title     = {Compare},
  author    = {Z},
  date      = {2014},
  publisher = {X and Y and Z},
}
@book{bookc1,
  title     = {Book C 1},
  author    = {Z},
  date      = {2011},
  publisher = {A {and} B and C {and} D and E {and} F},
}
@book{bookc2,
  title     = {Book C 2},
  author    = {Z},
  date      = {2012},
  publisher = {{A and B and C and D and E and F}},
}
@book{bookc3,
  title     = {Book C 3},
  author    = {Z},
  date      = {2013},
  publisher = {{A and B} and {C and D} and {E and F}},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

the `.bbl` file contains (abridged)

```
% book1
      \list{publisher}{1}{%
        {A {and} B, C {and} D, E {and} F}%
      }
% book2
      \list{publisher}{1}{%
        {A and B, C and D, E and F}%
      }
% book3
      \list{publisher}{1}{%
        {A and B}, {C and D}, {E and F}%
      }
```

where I would have expected

```
      \list{publisher}{1}{%
        {{A and B}, {C and D}, {E and F}}%
      }
```

for `book3` instead.

The problem here is that `biblatex` uses the outer braces to iterate over the list, so for `biblatex`

```
      \list{publisher}{1}{%
        {A and B}, {C and D}, {E and F}%
      }
```

looks more like a list with three entries, which would appear in the `.bbl` as

```
  \list{publisher}{3}{%
    {X}%
    {Y}%
    {Z}%
  }
```

Ultimately, the missing braces in make `biblatex` only grab the first bit `A and B` as content of the list.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, you have to treat lists of things as names of lists, mostly. That means, elements must be separated by `and`, what you did not do. The following code gives the expected result and changes the separator for the last list element into "&" for better visualization:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{biblatex}
\renewcommand*{\multilistdelim}{\addcomma\addspace}
\renewcommand*{\finallistdelim}{\addspace\&\addspace}

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{\jobname.bib}
@book{book3,
    title={Book 3},
    author={A.},
    date={2013},
    publisher={{Republic of Foo and Bar} and {Ministry of Education and Science} and {Office for Food and Agriculture}},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

\nocite{*}
\printbibliography[]

\end{document}
```

Comment: If we assume that we are talking about a single entity with a very long name, then `and` is simply not appropriate.